# Conditional form

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to give a few to conditionals to a contact form.

I already have one, when you select a city it shows an specific list of "especialidades" but now I need to show a different "horario" for each "especialidad" I try a few things but it just doesn't run.

I hope anyone could help me.

```js
jQuery('.datepicker').datepicker();
   function cambiar()
{
    if(jQuery("#selectciudad").val()=="Guayaquil"){ 
 jQuery('#select-especialidad').find('option').remove();              
 jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Alergologia">Alergologia</option>');  
 jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Cardiología">Cardiología</option>');
 jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Cirujia Vascular">Cirujia Vascular</option>');
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Colonoscopia">Colonoscopia</option>');
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Dermatologia">Dermatologia</option>'); 
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Fisioterapia">Fisioterapia</option>');  
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Gastroenterologia">Gastroenterologia</option>'); 
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Ginecologia">Ginecologia</option>'); 
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Laparoscopia">Laparoscipia</option>');  
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Medicina General">Medicina General</option>'); 
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Neumologia">Neumologia</option>'); 
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Nutricionista">Nutricionista</option>'); 
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Odontologia">Odontologia</option>'); 
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Otorrinolaringologia">Otorrinolaringologia</option>'); 
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Oftalmologia">Oftalmologia</option>'); 
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Optometrista">Optometrista</option>'); 
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Pediatria">Pediatria</option>'); 
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Proctologia">Proctologia</option>');
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Terapia Respiratoria">Terapia Respiratoria</option>');
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Traumatologia">Traumatologia</option>'); 
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Urologia">Urologia</option>'); 
  }

      if(jQuery("#selectespecialidad").val()=="Cardiologia"){
          jQuery("#select-horario").append('<option value="Sábados">Sábados </option>') 
}

lect-especialidad').find('option').remove();                 
 jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Cardiología">Cardiología</option>');
 jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Dermatologia">Dermatologia</option>');
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Endocrinologia">Endocrinologia</option>'); 
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Gastroenterologia">Gastroenterologia</option>'); 
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Ginecologia">Ginecologia</option>');   
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Otorrinolaringologia">Otorrinolaringologia</option>'); 
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Audiometria">Audiometria</option>'); 
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Oftalmologia">Oftalmologia</option>'); 
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Pediatria">Pediatria</option>'); 
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Fisioterapia">Fisioterapia</option>');
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Medicina General">Medicina General</option>');
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="RayoX">Rayos X</option>');
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Laboratorio">Laboratorio</option>');
jQuery("#select-especialidad").append('<option value="Urologia">Urologia</option>');
 

 }
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: My eyes! All joking aside, I'd suggest you indent your code correctly. It helps you and everyone else identify problems in your code faster. Have you [checked your console](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/javascript/185/hello-world/714/using-console-log#t=20161013160307338068) for errors?

Comment: Hmm. I think Someone here needs to learn the DRY principle, and how to use arrays and loops.

Comment: Show your full code

Comment: @MarcosSedrez thats all the code of the script

Comment: Thanks for your help. @evolutionxbox

Comment: Thanks for you answer.. I did it, I dont see any error. @MikeC

Comment: Show the HTML too.

Comment: There are many SO questions and web tutorials on making cascading menus. Google it.

Comment: @DanielBlanco sorry. I should've been a bit kinder

Comment: *Mother of God...*